# What is the story of Pushkaravarta clouds that cause Pralaya?

Tags: scripture, indra, pralaya, kalidasa

I came across this term while reading the Meghdootam by Kalidas. Pushkaravarta is the name of the flood clouds of the world-destroying deluge. **[This commentary](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=EY0qrYmJcPYC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=Pushkaravarta&source=bl&ots=iSsNJ9wJGc&sig=IXe7lkG-jKNPpmm2s1Ry_53lMwA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7s-Wm3KTZAhVDsY8KHfQZDgkQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=Pushkaravarta&f=false)** on the book states:

> Indra is the king of Heaven and the clouds. He sends us rain. The rain and the clouds obey his behest. When Brahma created the world, clouds sprang up in the lineage of King Pushkaravarata. It has been mentioned in the Brahmanda Purana that the cloud which brings the most terrible of rains is called
>   Pushkaravarta. When everything on the earth is to be destroyed, this cloud brings torrential rains. Below are the screenshots for reference.

[image: Screenshot 1 from the book]
[image: Screenshot 2 from the book]

**Is the story of these clouds being born in the lineage of the said king mentioned in any scriptures? Are there any other stories about them?**

Comment: According to [the Kurma Purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22296/5212), the clouds are Samvartaka clouds not Pushkaravrata clouds.

Comment: Yeah I have read that name but I want to know about these particular ones.

Comment: I think  they are mentioned in Yoga Vasishta . Will give it a try.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Great. I am looking for the story of their origin and whether they are personified as the descendants of the said king.

Comment: Yes will try to search , will take some time though :-)

Comment: @SwiftPushkar no worries it will be worth the wait am sure :)

Comment: Yoga-Vasistha 6.2.76  also said to be mentioning these clouds . But it seems that there is no verse no. 76 in that Yog- vashistha.

Comment: And your basic enquiry is about the story. Here I have provided basic answer about the mentioning of clouds from puranas. And haven't found any story yet ,but will update the answer soon. So consider this is not the exact answer but a part of that.

Answer (score 4):

**Definition** - Pushkaravarta — (from Pushkara, i.e. water, and vrita, to have place in, i.e., a watery cloud) a name for the flood clouds of the world-destroying deluge.

[**Vayu Purana**](http://archive.indianscriptures.com/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/vayu-mahapurana/text-with-translation/vol-i/chapter-51/topic-1) Chapter 51 Verse -37 - Tells us that they are class of clouds said to cause death or famine. And are generated from peak of the mountains.

> एते योजनमात्राच्च सार्धार्धान्निष्क्रुतादपि |
>  वृष्तिसर्गस्तथा
>   तेषां धारासारा: प्रकिर्तिता :||
>   **पुष्करावर्तका नाम ये  मेघा:** पक्षसंभवा: || Vayu 51.37||
>
> These clouds shower  forth from a distance of a Yojana , half a yojana
>   or one forth of yojana . They rain in continuous torrents
>   **Pushkaravartakas (an epithet of a class of clouds said to cause death of famine )** are the clouds that get generated from the peaks
>   of mountains.

---

Pushkaravarta Clouds are also  Mentioned in **Brahmnada Purana** Book 1- Part 2-Chapter 22- Verse 40. - Chapter Name - The Divine Luminaries , Varities Of Clouds . Divisions of Stratosphere. The Chariot of Sun God. - Page no. 218
Brahmanda Purana  gives us the detail explanation about them  , giving us the defination defination of Pushkaravarta clouds and tells us that "The clouds called Pushkaravarta are born of the wings of mountains . They increase thier size competing with the water and that is the reason they are called Pushkaravarta clouds ( Revolving Pushkaras) i.e. revolving clouds with water.

Here are the excerpts from Brahmanda Purana chapter.

> **40** Those clouds named Pushkaravartakas are born of the wings. Its conception is threefold .The shower is glorified as continuous
>   downpour.
>
> **42** Those clouds named Pushkara (were born of those wings ) . They increased in size competing with waters . For the reason , they are
>   termed Pushkaravartakas (Revolving Pushkaras) .
>
> **43** They Assue many forms. Their thundering sound is very terrible .They are the creation of torrential rain at the end of the Kalpas.
>   They control the Sarhvartaka fire (which burns down the universe then.
>
> **44** These (clouds) shower rain at the close of the Yugas ( Thus) those third (set of clouds) have been recounted . They have many
>   forms, configurations and     aggregates. They fill the earth.

Here you will find [**original sanskrit**](http://archive.indianscriptures.com/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/brahmanda-mahapuranam/vol-i/chapter-22/topic-1) shlokas and below is the screenshot.

---

Conclusion - The puranas tells us that the  Pushkaravartakas  are the clouds shower rain at the close of the Yugas . They are the creation of torrential rain at the end of the Kalpas. And basically they are  the flood clouds of the world-destroying deluge.

---

[image]

---

Note- Your basic enquiry is about the story. Here I have provided basic answer about the mentioning of clouds from puranas. And haven't found any story yet ,but will update the answer soon. So consider this is not the exact answer but a part of that.

Comment: Yes the story seems to be related to Indra and event of Indra cutting the wings of mountains. The story of Pushkaravartakas  is not clear from scriptures but we surely can see Indra and mountains in scriptures.- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16739/5620